# omitting 'a' in any phrase or sentence?

Tags: grammar, informal-language

> “It’s not a big part, but it’s a nice little part,” he said. “I got
> involved in the Mayberry thing over 20 years ago. I met the Howell
> brothers about three years ago at Mayberry Days in Mt. Airy, N.C., and
> we became good friends. After Stark Howell made his first trip to Mt.
> Airy, after a week of spending with us he said **‘I think I have an
> idea for movie script’**. A few months later he gave me a call and
> said ‘check your email’. He’d sent me a script for ‘Mayberry
> Misdemeanor’, which because ‘Mayberry Man’.

https://www.newsbug.info/wcinews/news/bluegrass-music-movie-more-takes-place-in-attica-mayberry-man-event/article_f01f981e-2104-5e63-bc23-434e4f48e597.html

The a is missing before movie script.

I used ChatGPT and it said that for informal speech omitting 'a' at any time is always acceptable, but is this really the case? It sounds plausible, but I am not sure, because I rarely hear people omit the 'a' when they talk. It always sounds like a mistake when I hear it.

Comment: That's a mistake, probably just a typo.

Comment: It's likely a typo, and ChatGPT is wrong.

Comment: It depends on the sentence, e.g.,  ‘I think I have an idea for movie script’ is *wrong*, but  ‘I think I have an idea for vacation’ is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typo and is not grammatically correct.

You can omit "the" in certain cases, but not "a".